# Calculating $P(X<Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ have Erlang distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am now stuck on a problem in "knowing the odds"

> Two light fixtures hang in different hallways of an apartment building. For each fixture, a given light bulb lasts an exponential time with mean $\lambda > 0$ before it has to be replaced. ($\lambda$ is the same for both.) There is a stack of $n$ replacement bulbs in a closet in hallway $A$, and $k$ replacement bulbs in the corresponding closet in hallway $B$. What is the probability that hallway $A$ runs out of bulbs before $B$ does?

My attempt:

> If we want that hallway $A$ runs out of bulbs before $B$ does, it means the total time of light in hall $A$ is less than that in hall $B$. If we use $X$ denote the total time of light in hall $A$ and $Y$ denote that in hall $B$, then we want to calculate $P(X<Y)$. $X$ is the sum of $n$ i.i.d random variables with exponential distribution with mean $\lambda$, so $X$ has Erlang distribution density ${\displaystyle {\frac {\lambda ^{-n}x^{n-1}e^{-\lambda x}}{(n-1)!}}}$ where $Y$ has Erlang distribution density ${\displaystyle {\frac {\lambda ^{-k}y^{k-1}e^{-\lambda y}}{(k-1)!}}}$. So $$P(X<Y)=\int_{0}^{\infty} f_{Y}(y)\int_{0}^{y} f_{X}(x)dx\,dy.$$

Can someone help me with $P(X<Y)$? I don't know how to calculate the probability since the integral seems too complicated

Comment: First step analysis -- you know a bulb will burn out with probability one... what is the probability that the first one is from A?  Once you know this you can realize this is a 'problem of points', so to speak

Comment: You are tacitly assuming independence of $X$ and $Y$, which should be mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer, just an idea which you can hopefully finalize. Each time a lamp goes off, it can be either from $A$ or $B$. Since the exponential distribution is memoryless, the events $\{i\text{th blown lamp is from }A\}$, $i\ge 1$, are independent, and since the exponential distributions are the same, they have probability $1/2$.

Thus, the problem is reduced to the following:

> Calculate the probability of flipping $n$ heads before $k$ tails with a symmetric coin.

Please write if you would difficulties solving it or formalizing the equivalence.